# Comando de INPUT do Python apararece na aba OUTPUT

Tags: python

Quando dou um comando de INPUT ele aparece na aba OUTPUT do Terminal e pelo fato de estar na aba OUTPUT ele não permite que eu digite nada.

Como faço para ele aparecer na aba TERMINAL...?
Estou usando Ubuntu com VSCODE
Obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu já passei pelo mesmo problema, tem uma forma que funciona mas não é o ideal acredito.

1. Observe que na parte superior do **VS** tem a aba '*DEBUG*',
   clique nela.
2. Ira abrir uma janela com algumas possibilidades, clique no "*RUN
   WITHOUT DEBUGINGG*".
3. Após isso o seu código ira abrir no terminal e ira funcionar.